# Flatten complex object/nested object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

I would like to flatten an object in Typescript. I have tried using lodash flatMapDeep, but get an endless loop.

```
{
    "extensionId": 1,
        "assetId": 1996323923,
            "extensionName": "Extension 1",
                "terms": [
                    {
                        "extensionTermId": 2,
                        "extensionId": 1,
                        "modificationVersion": 0,
                        "tests": [
                            {
                                "extensionTestId": 1,
                                "extensionTermId": 2,
                                "testTypeId": 1,
                                "testTypeName": "Debt Yield",
                            },
                            {
                                "extensionTestId": 2,
                                "extensionTermId": 2,
                                "testTypeId": 3,
                                "testTypeName": "LTV",
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                ]
}
```

Here is the interface I'm using for the object.

```
export interface IExtension {
    [key: string]: any;
    extensionId: number | null,
    assetId: number | null,
    extensionName: string | null,
    terms: IExtensionTerms,
}

export interface IExtensionTerms {
    [key: string]: any;
    extensionTermId: number | null,
    extensionId: number | null,
    modificationVersion: number | null,
    tests: IExtensionTest,
}

export interface IExtensionTest {
    extensionTestId: number | null,
    extensionTermId: number | null,
    testTypeId: number | null,
    testTypeName: string | null,
}
```

I have tried using lodash flatMapDeep, but it overloads the function in an endless loop. Is there another way that I can get the result?

```
const flattenExtensions = (extension: IExtension[]) => {
    const getTests = (): any => {
        if(!extension || !extension.length) {
            console.log(extension);
            return extension;
        }
        console.log(extension);
        return [extension, flatMapDeep(extension, getTests)]
    }

    flatMapDeep(extension, getTests)
};
```

I'd like the following format for the result array.

```
[
    {
        "extensionId": 1,
        "assetId": 1996323923,
        "extensionName": "Extension 1",
        "modificationVersion": 0,
        "extensionTestId": 2,
        "extensionTermId": 2,
        "testTypeId": 3,
        "testTypeName": "LTV",
    },
]
```

Comment: What's the result you'd like to have?

Comment: I've modified the question to show the result array that I'd like for the first entry.

Comment: Is there only 1 term every time? If there could be multiple, (which I am assuming to be the case), what would you expect to happen? Multiple entries with the same extensionId or should only the first term be used?

Comment: There could be multiple terms. I would expect a separate array for each extensionTermId and each extensionTestId.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated code** : as per comment added extra fields in returned object. Explanation is given in comments.

References :

1. [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
2. [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Here is the updated function.

```
const flattenExtensions = (extension) => {
  // if extension is object then convert it into array, so that we can directly apply .flatMap on it.
  let ext = Array.isArray(extension) ? extension : [extension];

  // flatten the arrays
  // get flat test object with nested flatMaps from extension object and then terms object.
  return ext.flatMap(e =>
    e.terms.flatMap(t =>
      // use .map() to add some additional properties into returned object
      t.tests.map(tst =>
        ({
          extensionId: e.extensionId,
          assetId: e.assetId,
          extensionName: e.extensionName,
          modificationVersion: t.modificationVersion,
          ...tst
        })
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Try it below.

```js
let extension = [{
  "extensionId": 1,
  "assetId": 1996323923,
  "extensionName": "Extension 1",
  "terms": [{
    "extensionTermId": 2,
    "extensionId": 1,
    "modificationVersion": 0,
    "tests": [{
        "extensionTestId": 1,
        "extensionTermId": 2,
        "testTypeId": 1,
        "testTypeName": "Debt Yield",
      },
      {
        "extensionTestId": 2,
        "extensionTermId": 2,
        "testTypeId": 3,
        "testTypeName": "LTV",
      },
    ]
  }, ]
}];

const flattenExtensions = (extension) => {
  // if extension is object then convert it into array, so that we can directly apply .flatMap on it.
  let ext = Array.isArray(extension) ? extension : [extension];

  // flatten the arrays
  // get flat test object with nested flatMaps from extension object and then terms object.
  return ext.flatMap(e =>
    e.terms.flatMap(t =>
      // use .map() to add some additional properties into returned object
      t.tests.map(tst =>
        ({
          extensionId: e.extensionId,
          assetId: e.assetId,
          extensionName: e.extensionName,
          modificationVersion: t.modificationVersion,
          ...tst
        })
      )
    )
  );
}

// pass extension array
let test = flattenExtensions(extension);
console.log('test', test);

// pass extension object
let test2 = flattenExtensions(extension[0]);
console.log('test2', test2);
```

---

**Old answer**

You can simply do it like below. In question you have added `object` of `extension`.

```
let tests = extension.terms.flatMap(t => t.tests);
```

If you have array of `extension` then you can do like below.

```
let tests = extension.flatMap(e => e.terms.flatMap(t => t.tests));
```

To combine both (array and object), you can write your function like below.

```
const flattenExtensions = (extension) => {
  // if passed object is an array then use nested flatMap.
  // else single flatMap is enough
  if (Array.isArray(extension)) {
    return extension.flatMap(e => e.terms.flatMap(t => t.tests));
  } else {
    return extension.terms.flatMap(t => t.tests);
  }
}
```

Try it here.

```js
let extension = [{
  "extensionId": 1,
  "assetId": 1996323923,
  "extensionName": "Extension 1",
  "terms": [{
    "extensionTermId": 2,
    "extensionId": 1,
    "modificationVersion": 0,
    "tests": [{
        "extensionTestId": 1,
        "extensionTermId": 2,
        "testTypeId": 1,
        "testTypeName": "Debt Yield",
      },
      {
        "extensionTestId": 2,
        "extensionTermId": 2,
        "testTypeId": 3,
        "testTypeName": "LTV",
      },
    ]
  }, ]
}];

const flattenExtensions = (extension) => {
  // if passed object is an array then use nested flatMap.
  // else single flatMap is enough
  if (Array.isArray(extension)) {
    return extension.flatMap(e => e.terms.flatMap(t => t.tests));
  } else {
    return extension.terms.flatMap(t => t.tests);
  }
}

// pass extension array
let test = flattenExtensions(extension);
console.log('test', test);

// pass extension object
let test2 = flattenExtensions(extension[0]);
console.log('test2', test2);
```

Comment: Hi Karan, the array is missing extensionId, assetId, extensionName & modificationVersion. How can I have these in the array?

Answer (score 0):

A function that recursively walks an object tree and collects all (enumerable) properties that don't contain objects.

```js
function _flatten(acc, value, key) {
  if (typeof value !== "object" || value === null) {
    acc[key] = value;
  } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.reduce(_flatten, acc);
  } else {
    for (let k in value) acc = _flatten(acc, value[k], k);
  }
  return acc;
}

function flatten(value) {
  return _flatten({}, value);
}

console.log(flatten({
  "extensionId": 1,
  "assetId": 1996323923,
  "extensionName": "Extension 1",
  "terms": [{
    "extensionTermId": 2,
    "extensionId": 1,
    "modificationVersion": 0,
    "tests": [{
        "extensionTestId": 1,
        "extensionTermId": 2,
        "testTypeId": 1,
        "testTypeName": "Debt Yield",
      },
      {
        "extensionTestId": 2,
        "extensionTermId": 2,
        "testTypeId": 3,
        "testTypeName": "LTV",
      },
    ]
  }, ]
}));
```

Careful, doesn't handle cyclic references.

Comment: Hi Thomas, this only returns one array. I'd want to return 2 arrays in this example since testTypeId has different value (2 & 3) in the objects.